# Tkinter learning how to use pack and grid the hard way

Tags: button, grid, tkinter, label, python-imaging-library

This was my very first post to stack overflow.
I put together my first python Tkinter software after googling info all day.
Much to my frustration when I ran my first software tkinter kepted thinking to it's self and not producing any errors or displaying anything.
I decided to post my code on stack overflow.

Please read my Python code # explanes how Python works:

```
#load the normal drivers
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from Tkconstants import *
# this makes the master app window
master = Tk()
master.geometry('+0+0')
master.wm_title("App Window")
frame = Frame(master, height=300, width=700, background="black")
frame.pack_propagate(0)
#intro image on the right column
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="1.gif")
panel = tk.Label(master, image = img).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
#code to put Buttons into the left column Label
panel2 = tk.Label().grid(row = 1, column = 1)
#onClick commands I will work on Later.
def onClick1():
    master.image = PhotoImage(file="captain_scarlett.gif")
    w = Label(master, image=master.image)
    w.photo = master
    w.pack(side=RIGHT) 
def onClick2():
    photo = PhotoImage(file="1.gif")
    w = Label(master, image=photo)
    w.photo = photo
    w.pack(side=RIGHT)
def onClick3():
    photo = PhotoImage(file="1.gif")
    w = Label(master, image=photo)
    w.photo = photo
    w.pack(side=RIGHT)
def onClick4():
    photo = PhotoImage(file="1.gif")
    w = Label(master, image=photo)
    w.photo = photo
    w.pack(side=RIGHT)
#these are the Buttons that go into left column      
master.Button1 = Button(panel2, text="captain_scarlet",  fg="#000",    
width=17, background="yellow", command=onClick1) 
master.Button2 = Button(panel2, text="Page 2",  fg="#000", width=17,    
background="yellow", command=onClick2)
master.Button3 = Button(panel2, text="Page 3",  fg="#000", width=17,   
background="yellow", command=onClick3)
master.Button4 = Button(panel2, text="Page 4",  fg="#000", width=17,   
background="yellow", command=onClick4)
#normal exiting commands    
frame.pack()
master.mainloop()
```

The answer I got changed my whole understanding of how Tkinter works and is formated.

Comment: you seemed to have changed your question to a statement. Why was that? This site is for questions, and answers to questions. If you go back and significantly change the question then the answers will stop making sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are mixing `grid` and `pack` in the same window. You cannot do that. One of them will take control and resize the widgets according to its rules. Then, the other will see that one or more widgets has changed size and try to readjust according to the new size. This might cause some other widgets to change size, causing the first one to notice and readjust. This will go on forever.

You can mix `grid` and `pack` in the same application, but you can't use them both to control the same containing widget.

Comment: ok so everthing that's pack() I need to relearn the grid() way to do the same Tkinter codes. I'll spend all day Reading, Editing, saving, runing. Thanks for the advice I feel I can get this to work by the end of today.

Answer (score 0):

I had better show you the answer to my problem
I had to convert this pack code

```
def onClick1():
    master.image = PhotoImage(file="captain_scarlett.gif")
    w = Label(master, image=master.image)
    w.photo = master
    w.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

And make the code useable on a grid without giving Tkinter a headache

```
def but1():
    img = Image.open("captain_scarlett.gif")
    intro = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    right = Label(win, image=intro)
    right.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=14)
    right.image=intro
```

I hope this information helps people get out of the Tkinter trap that I fell into at some later date in time.